# Can we have more than one field in g:select optionValue?

Tags: grails

Is there any way to show more than one field name in optionValue?

```
<g:select name="id" from="${Books.list()}" optionKey="id"
          value="" optionValue="name"
          noSelection="${['null':'Select Publisher...']}"/>
```

Expe:

```
<g:select name="id" from="${Books.list()}" optionKey="id"
          value="" optionValue="name and author"
          noSelection="${['null':'Select Publisher...']}"/>
```

Answer (score 43):

You can pass a closure for your option value if you don't want to modify your domain class:

```
<g:select name="id" from="${Books.list()}" optionKey="id"
          value="" optionValue="${{it.name +' '+it.author}}"
          noSelection="${['null':'Select Publisher...']}"/>
```

Comment: This works wonderfully but my IDE (IntelliJ) is marking this as an ambiguous code block error.  Has anyone got around this?

Comment: I always forget how can I perform that! Thanks! =D

Answer (score 10):

You could introduce a transient property in your domain class, which you can use in the optionValue of the g:select:

```
class Book {
    String name
    String author

    static transients = [ 'nameAndAuthor' ]

    public String getNameAndAuthor() {
        return "$name, $author"
    }
}
```

Your g:select looks then like:

```
<g:select name="id" from="${Books.list()}" optionKey="id" value="" 
    optionValue="nameAndAuthor" 
    noSelection="${['null':'Select Publisher...']}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Or add a toString Method to your Book class

```
public String toString() {
"${name} ${author}"
}
```

then just omit the optionValue

```
<g:select name="id" from="${Books.list()}" optionKey="id"
          value="" noSelection="${['null':'Select Publisher...']}"/>
```

Atleast then when you look at the domain in your debugger it had a human recognizable value.

Hope this helps.